Application of Stone's theorem to regular representation
Consider the left regular representation
$$\lambda: \mathbb{R}\to U(L^2(\mathbb{R})), \quad (\lambda_x f)(y) = f(y-x), \quad x,y \in \mathbb{R}.$$
By Stone's theorem, there is a positive, self-adjoint, injective unbounded operator $A$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$\lambda_x = A^{ix}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}.$$
Question: Can we give an explicit description of $A$? Concretely, what is the domain of $A$ (or at least a core for $A$) and how does $A$ act on this domain (or core)?

Note that the Fourier transform of $\lambda_x f$ is,
$$\begin{split}
\mathcal{F}(\lambda_x f)(\xi) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y-x)e^{-i\xi y} \, dy\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y’)e^{-i\xi (y’+x)} \, dy’\\
&= e^{-i \xi x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)e^{-i\xi y} \, dy\\
&= (e^{-\xi})^{ix} \mathcal{F}(f)(\xi)
\end{split}$$
So $A$ acts as the Fourier multiplier by the function $e^{-\xi}$. Recall that $\frac{d}{dy}$ acts as the Fourier multiplier by $i\xi$, so $A = e^{i \frac{d}{dy}}$.
The domain of $A$ is, of course, all $L^2$ functions with Fourier transforms that are still in $L^2$ after multiplying by $e^{-\xi}$. On a core of $A$ (consisting of functions whose derivatives grow “slow enough” as the order goes to infinity, say), we have,
$$Af = e^{i\frac{d}{dy}}f = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{i^n}{n!} f^{(n)}$$

It's $i x = \partial_y$, the derivative as generator, its exponential series the functional generating the translation  $y\to (1+ x \partial_y) y = y+x$ by a Taylor series.
$\partial$ is an unbounded operator over all of $\mathbb R$. It's Fourier transform $\mathbb F(\partial) \mathit F(f)(k) = i k \mathit F(f)(k)   $ is the multiplication, its domain is roughly the subspace of functions with Fourier transform $\mathit F(f)(k)$ such that $k*\mathit F(f)(k) \in \mathit L^2$, since the Fourier transform is unitary.
